# preg_match white space

Tags: php

I would like to ask you about regular expressions preg_match have outlined below. I wish to express their approval to add white space. For one and the other expression. I know that white space is represented by a /s But I can not deal with it. please help

```
    'string' => array(
        'pattern' => '^([a-zA-Z ]+)$',
    ),

    'numericString' => array(
        'pattern' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$',
    )

    'numeric' => array(
        'pattern' => '^[0-9]+$',
    ),
```

Please help i need add white space to any.

Comment: It's `\s` not `/s`. And your first example already contains spaces. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html and http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White space is represented by `\s` in PCRE syntax, not `/s`. Try this:

```
'string' => array(
    'pattern' => '^([a-zA-Z\s]+)$',
),

'numericString' => array(
    'pattern' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$',
)

'numeric' => array(
    'pattern' => '^[0-9\s]+$',
),
```

You may find this site helpful for testing regexes with visualisations of matches:
http://www.regexpal.com/